# how to make jquery search to work with dynamic list view?

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am trying to use the data-filter="true" feature on listview. I found that it work only with static lists (namely, all li elements are listed in the html file). With dynamically generated lists it does not work. Seems like it needs to be reinitialized somehow. Here is what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>View Events</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="script/jquery.mobile-1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="script/jquery.mobile-1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/pure_min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="view-events">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h3>
        View Events of <span id="events-for-pump-id" class="pump-id">...</span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul id="events" data-role="listview" style="display: none;" data-filter="true">
        <li class="events code"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).on('pageinit', '#view-events', function() {

                        $('#events-for-pump-id').autoRender({
                            'pump-id' : 123
                        });
                        $('#events').autoRender({
                            events : [ {
                                code : 1
                            }, {
                                code : 2
                            }, {
                                code : 3
                            } ]
                        });

                        $('#events').show();
                    });
                </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this on casual googling http://www.elijahmanor.com/2011/02/dynamically-appending-elements-to.html, have u checked it??